# Check if any of a JSON's field's subfield contains a value (PHP)

Tags: php, json, string, loops, strpos

I want to check if any of a JSON field's sub-fields contain a string. I do not know the number of sub-fields beforehand.

In particular, I want to see if any of ...

```
$obj['message']['license'][**0**]['URL']
$obj['message']['license'][**1**]['URL']
$obj['message']['license'][**2**]['URL']
$obj['message']['license'][**3**]['URL']
$obj['message']['license'][**XYZ**]['URL']
```

... (where **XYZ** can be any number depending on the number of sub-fields under the `license`-field) contain the value `creativecommons`.

If yes, then a variable called `$oa_lic` shall be that value that contains `creativecommons`, else `$oa_lic` shall be `NULL`.

**Example 1**: at https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1002/poi3.263, `$oa_lic` should be `NULL`.

**Example 2**: at https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1016/j.polgeo.2021.102404, `$oa_lic` should be `http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/`.

I already have the code for doing that if **XYZ** is merely `0`:

```
<?php
$crossrefurl = "https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1016/j.polgeo.2021.102404";

// make request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $crossrefurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// convert response
$obj = json_decode($output, true);

if(!isset($obj['message']['license'][0]['URL'])) {
    echo '<p><u>OA License</u>: none</p>';
    $oa_lic = NULL;
}
else {
  if(isset($obj['message']['license'][0]['delay-in-days'])) {
    if($obj['message']['license'][0]['delay-in-days'] == 0) {
      if(strpos($obj['message']['license'][0]['URL'], 'creativecommons') !== false) {
        $oa_lic = $obj['message']['license'][0]['URL'];
        echo '<p><u>OA License</u>: '.$oa_lic.'</p>';
      }
      else {
        $oa_lic = NULL;
        echo '<p><u>OA License</u>: there is a license, but it is not Creative Commons</p>';
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $oa_lic = NULL;
    echo '<p><u>OA License</u>: there seems to be an embargo?</p>';
  }
}
```

But how to count efficiently the number of subfields under `licenses` and then to check if any of their subfield `URL` contain the string `creativecommons`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over `$obj['message']['license']` then get element count with `count($obj['message']['license'])`. After you know this count value you can do what you what with it.